# C#: TCPSocket read & write best practice

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have an issue with my C#/Unity code.
I tried to use `while(true)` but it's not working and has the infinite loop.

Explain please what's the problem there? How could I do reading and writing to socket all the time while the socket is alive?

Thank you.

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1442);
byte[] message = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonUtility.ToJson(new Message()));
clientSocket.Send(message);
while(true) {
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int receivedDataLength = clientSocket.Receive(data);
    string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);
    Debug.Log(stringData);
}
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: There are infinite loop and application are slowing down...

Comment: Use async/await with comms.  You started off by saying this was for Unity so I'm not sure if it supports it though.  If so, use BeginReceive

Comment: Well, I thought it isn't related things...

Comment: At one point Unity didn't support Mono > 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Found the easy solution with `System.Threading`.

```
void Start()
{
    clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1442);
    byte[] message = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonUtility.ToJson(new GameMessage("ship/spawn", "")));
    clientSocket.Send(message);
    Thread polling = new Thread(HandleResponse);
    polling.Start();
}

void HandleResponse()
{
    while (true)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[8056];
        int receivedDataLength = clientSocket.Receive(data);
        string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);
        Debug.Log(stringData);
    }
}
```